# reducing this problem to a decision problem

Tags: subset-sum, first-order-logic, embeddings

Before I can define my problem, let's make a simple definition. An expression $e$ is a conjunction of inequalities of the form $x~ op~ v$ where: $x$ is a variable, $op\in[<,>,\leq,\geq,=]$, and $v$ is an integer value. For instance, the expression $e=age\geq 45 \wedge exp\geq 10$ aims to find all persons satisfying some conditions over $age$ and $experience$.

$\textbf{Problem statement:}$ Given an expression $e$ and a set of expressions $E=\{e_1,...e_n\}$, is there a subset $E_s$ of $E$ that covers all points of $e$ ? I.e. all results of $e$ are all returned by $E_s$.

$\underline{Example}:$

"$e=age\geq 45 \wedge exp\geq 10$"  $\textbf{is covered}$ by $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ where:

"$e_1=age>30 \wedge age<37 \wedge exp\geq 10$", "$e_2=age\geq 37 \wedge exp > 8 \wedge exp < 15$", "$e_3=age\geq 37 \wedge exp\geq 15$".

$\underline{Explanation}:$

By merging $e_2$ with $e_3$ we obtain the expression "$e_{23}=age\geq 37 \wedge exp > 8 $"

By merging $e_1$ with $e_{23}$ we obtain the expression "$e_{123}=age > 30 \wedge exp > 8 $"

It is clear the $e$ is $\textbf{covered by}$ $e_{123}$.

$\textbf{My Question:}$ Is there some theoretical problem that can be reduced to this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by the "points of $e$"?  What do you mean by the "results of $e$" and "returned by $E_s$"?  Please define these terms.  An example is not a substitute for a clear definition.  Do you mean for every assignment that satisfies $e$ also satisfies one of the expressions in $E_s$?  If so, isn't the question equivalent to asking whether every assignment that satisfies $e$ also satisfies one of the expressions in $E$ (since we can take $E_s=E$)?

Comment: What is your real question?  Do you want to know the complexity of this problem?  What's the motivation or context in which you encountered it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is coNP-hard, by reduction from SAT.  In particular, using inequalities $x \ge 1$, $x \le 0$ and interpreting $0$ as false and $1$ as true, we can encode any SAT formula $\varphi$ into this form (each clause $\varphi$ gets translated into an expression, each literal in the clause is translated into one of the two inequalities listed above, and we take $e$ to be the expression $x \ge 0$, i.e., an expression that is always satisfied).

Moreover, your problem is in coNP and in practice can be solved with a SAT solver.  Let $c_{i,1},\dots,c_{i,k}$ denote the set of integer constants that appear in some inequality together with the variable $x_i$.  Assume $c_{i,1},\dots,c_{i,k}$ have been put into sorted order.  This defines the intervals $(-\infty,c_{i,1}),[c_{i,1},c_{i,1}],(c_{i,1},c_{i,2}),[c_{i,2},c_{i,2}],\dots,(c_{i,k},\infty)$.  Introduce boolean variables $v_{i,J}$, one per interval $J$, where $v_{i,J}$ is interpreted as meaning that $x_i < J$.  In this way, every inequality can be translated into a disjunction of literals.  We also add the disjunctions $\vee_J x_{i,J}$ and the $\neg x_{i,J_1} \lor \neg x_{i,J_2}$ for each $i$ and each two different intervals $J_1,J_2$.  Proceeding in this way we can convert $e$ into a conjunction of disjunctions, and we can convert $\wedge_{f \in E} \neg f$ into a conjunction of disjunctions (using the Tseitin transform as needed), and thus convert your problem into a CNF formula, which will be satisfiable iff $E$ does not cover all of $e$.

Comment: while waiting for an answer, I had already thought about reduction from SAT, nevertheless the details you gave me are very helpful and some of them escaped me. Thank you so much

Comment: @mahou_2019, doesn't this answer your question?  If so please mark the answer as accepted, thanks.